# VB.Net - Adding WebApi 5 to Existing MVC 5 Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing VB MVC5 site and I am trying to add WebApi.

I am following this tutorial: [Adding Web API Support to an Existing ASP.NET MVC Project](https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/30/adding-web-api-support-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-project/)

The tutorial examples use C# so I have been converting to VB.

I am on step 2.2, adding the Global.asax configuration changes **but I am getting the error:**

> Argument not specified for parameter 'Config' of 'Public Sub Register(config As HttpConfiguration)'.

**This is what I have for App_Start\WebApiConfig.vb:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Http

Namespace myProjectName.App_Start
    Public Module WebApiConfig
        Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)

            ' Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name:="DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            )
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

**This is what I have for Global.asax.vb:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Optimization
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.SessionState
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Routing
Imports mySolutionName.myProjectName.App_Start

Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Protected Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) '// <-- Error here
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In VB, `WebApiConfig.Register` calls the method. If you want to pass a delegate, that would be `AddressOf WebApiConfig.Register`.

Comment: @GSerg Doh! TY. If you want to post as answer ill accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, `WebApiConfig.Register` without the trailing parentheses, passes the method itself as a delegate. `WebApiConfig.Register()` would call the method and pass its result to the outer function.

In VB, `WebApiConfig.Register`, with or without the parentheses, will always call the method. To pass the method itself as a delegate you need to use [`AddressOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addressof-operator):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf WebApiConfig.Register)
```